# How can I skip a "should" block/fragment in specs2?

Tags: scala, specs2

Suppose I have a specs2 specification defined in the "unit" style as follows:

```
import org.specs2.mutable

class MyClassSpec extends mutable.Specification {
  "myMethod" should {
    "return positive values" in {
      MyClass.myMethod must beGreaterThan(0)
    }

    "return values less than 100" in {
      MyClass.myMethod must beLessThan(100)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to skip/disable/mark pending all of the examples within the should block/fragment for `myMethod`?

Obviously I can call `pendingUntilFixed` or return `pending` from each individual example in the block, but this would be rather tedious for a block with many specifications.

It seems like this would be a common occurrence if `MyClass.myMethod` is difficult to implement and gets punted.  Is there another way that this is commonly done in specs2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mix in the `Tags` trait and define any `section` you want:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

class MyClassSpec extends Specification with Tags {

  section("pending")
  "myMethod" should {
    "return positive values" in {
      MyClass.myMethod must beGreaterThan(0)
    }

    "return values less than 100" in {
      MyClass.myMethod must beLessThan(100)
    }
  }
  section("pending")
}
```

Then you run your specification with `exclude pending`

```
>test-only *MyClassSpec* -- exclude pending
```

This is documented [here](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#In+a+unit+specification).

You can also use an implicit context to make sure that all your examples in the `should` block are `PendingUntilFixed`:

```
import org.specs2._
import execute._

class MyClassSpec extends mutable.Specification { 
  "this doesn't work for now" >> {
    implicit val puf = pendingContext("FIXME")
    "ex1" in ko
    "ex2" in ok
  }
  "but this works ok" >> {
    "ex3" in ko // maybe not here ;-)
    "ex4" in ok
  }

  def pendingContext(reason: String) = new mutable.Around {
    def around[T <% Result](t: =>T) = 
      t.pendingUntilFixed(reason)
  }
}
```

***Update for specs2 3.x***

```
import org.specs2._
import execute._

class TestMutableSpec extends mutable.Specification {
  "this doesn't work for now" >> {
    implicit def context[T] = pendingContext[T]("FIXME")

    "ex1" in ko
    "ex2" in ok
  }
  "but this works ok" >> {
    "ex3" in ko // maybe not here ;-)
    "ex4" in ok
  }

   def pendingContext[T](reason: String): AsResult[MatchResult[T]] =     
     new AsResult[MatchResult[T]] {
      def asResult(t: =>MatchResult[T]): Result =
        AsResult(t).pendingUntilFixed(reason)
     }
}
```

Comment: Sure, that'll do.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to make the fragments show up as pending in the output?  When they are excluded, they become a bit more difficult to remember to fix (at least, for me).

Comment: Hi @Eric is it possible to do this with the (implicit: ev T => Result) syntax?  I gave it a shot but couldn't find anything that worked.  Also thanks for always supporting your library!  Nice work :-)

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm updating the question with an answer for 3.x.